# Recursively process video files to make space

Tags: video, display-resolution, ffmpeg, storage, convert

I've maxed the storage space I have and I would like to make some space.

I've thought of converting all files to mkv and down-scaling high resolution files to a lower resolution.

So to convert mp4 to mkv there is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mkv
```

And to downscale there is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=$w:$h <encoding-parameters> output.mp4
```

but I need to convert all files not a single mp4 one, I need to remove the input file after done processing it and I have to do this only for files above a given resolution. Also I would like to keep the aspect ratio and I don't know if this is doing that.

There is a tool called [video-diet](https://github.com/hiancdtrsnm/video-diet) that does part of this.

This is what I would like to do

```
Recursively find every file under the current directory
If the file resolution has a height equal or greater to a given height.
  Convert the file to mkv if it's in another format avi, mp4, flv, etc
  Downscale to a lower resolution height, keeping the aspect ratio.
```

Maybe I should also [lower the frame rate](https://superuser.com/questions/1187149/change-frame-rate-without-changing-film-speed-duration) to 24 fps?

If there is a better way, I would like to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script to get you started. You'll probably want to modify this to suit your needs, add options to ffmpeg if you want to change the framerate, etc.

Note there's a conditional in there checking if the file is already an .mkv, but I'm not actually doing something different with them, so the conditional is kind of pointless. It's just there because your question made it sound as if you wanted to do something different with them, though I'm not sure why. FFMPEG can scale and convert at the same time.

But if you do want to do something different, change the ffmpeg line for when the conditional is true to something different.

```
#!/bin/bash

# set the resolution above which you want to downscale
maxwidth=1920
maxheight=1080

# set the resolution to downscale to; the width will be
# calculated to preserve aspect ratio
targetwidth=1280

# a counter for errors
errors=0

# recursively find video files; add their names to
# an array to process
mapfile -t filenames < <(find $(pwd) -type f -iregex '.*avi$\|.*mp4$\|.*m4v$\|.*flv\|.*mkv\|.*ogv\|.*webm$\|.*mov')

# loop through the array
for filename in "${filenames[@]}" ; do
    # get the resolution with ffprobe
    res="$(ffprobe -hide_banner -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -print_format csv "$filename")"
    # strip "stream" off "res"
    res="${res#stream,}"
    # parse into width and height
    width="${res%,*}"
    height="${res#*,}"
    # compare to maxwidth/height to see if it should be
    # processed
    if [[ "$width" -ge "$maxwidth" ]] || [[ "$height" -ge "$maxheight" ]] ; then
        # determine the output name
        outputname="${filename%.*}-downscaled.mkv"
        # check if output already exists; if so, skip it
        if [[ -e "$outputname" ]] ; then
            continue
        fi
        # calculate targetheight, divide by 2 multiply by 2
        # to ensure it's even
        targetheight="$(( ( ( (targetwidth * height) / width) / 2) * 2 ))"
        # get file extension
        ext="${filename##*.}"
        # do something different with mkvs?
        # not sure why you would though
        if [[ "$ext" =~ '[Mm]{Kk][Vv]' ]] ; then
            ffmpeg -i "$filename" -vf scale="$targetwidth:$targetheight" "$outputname"
            exitcode="$?"
        else
            ffmpeg -i "$filename" -vf scale="$targetwidth:$targetheight" "$outputname"
            exitcode="$?"
        fi
        # if conversion was a success, delete original file
        if [[ "$exitcode" == 0 ]] && [[ -e "$outputname" ]] ; then
            rm "$filename"
        else
            echo
            echo "Error processing $filename" >&2
            echo "Not deleted!"
            let errors++
            echo
        fi
    fi
done

# report number of errors if there were any
if [[ "$errors" == 0 ]] ; then
    exit 0
fi
echo "There were $errors errors!" >&2
exit 1
```

That might be kind of overkill, and there may be ways to simplify it, but that's what I'd do.

Comment: Is it converting non mkv files to mkv? It's seems that it's only downscaling. Change the `gt` for greater or equal.

Comment: In your question, the "Convert the file to mkv if it's in another format avi, mp4, flv, etc" is *after* the "If the file resolution has a height equal or greater to a given height", so I was assuming you only wanted to convert *those* videos, not videos already in a smaller resolution, though the changes aren't great if you want it to convert all non-mkv's.

Comment: I changed the `-gt` (for greater than) to `-ge` (greater than or equal to).